# Integer return types in Java

Tags: java, c, return, return-type

So I have a quick question about Java.

So in C, some methods (especially the main) look like this:

```
int main(){
    printf("Test");
    return 0;
}
```

The int return type as some C developers on here may know shows if the method returns an error or not, with 0 being the return showing that there isn't an error. So I thought, well, if I did something like this as a method in Java:

```
public int test(){
    return 0;
}
```

Would the integer return show that there is/isn't an error returned?

Comment: C does not support _methods_, `main` is a function. And that is not the correct signature. Also there is no definition about the meaning of the value returned by the standard. Most OSes, however, only define negative values to represent errors typically and the only convention is that `0` signals "normal termination".

Answer (score 4):

> Would the integer return show that there is/isn't an error returned?

Not usually, although every API designer can make their own choices.

Normally, in Java, an *error* is modelled as an `Exception` and is thrown rather than returned. (As is the case with modern C++, as I understand it.)

So for instance, if you had a function that parsed integers, you might have:

```
int parseInt(String str) throws NumberFormatException {
    // ...implementation
}
```

If `parseInt` returns, it's returned *successfully*. Otherwise, it throws. You'd use it like this:

```
try {
    int value = parseInt(str);
    doSomethingWith(value);
    // more main-line code here
    // ...
}
catch (NumberFormatException ex) {
    // Deal with the exceptional case of an invalid input
}
```

[This tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/) on Oracle's Java site goes into detail around exceptions and exception handling.

Now, sometimes you may have a method that should return an `int` or a flag indicating a *non-exceptional* condition indicating the `int` isn't available. Since it's normal, you expect it to happen, it shouldn't be an exception, but you still need to flag it up somehow. In that situation, one option is to use `Integer` instead of `int` and return `null` in the non-exception case where the `int` isn't available. `Integer` is an object type corresponding to the primitive `int`. Java's auto-boxing and auto-unboxing makes it fairly straightforward to use `Integer` in these situations.

What ends up being "exceptional" or "non-exception" is very much a judgement call, and consequently you see different API designers doing things slightly differently.

Answer (score 1):

In C `main`'s return value is copied into the exit code value of the process.

In Java, the JVM is really what is running, and it just "starts" the user provided set of classes according to the method `public static void main(String[] args)` in the class you provide to the command line.

So your class doesn't actually exit, the `java` program exits.  That said, there is a way to get the `java` program to return with a specific exit code.  You call `System.exit(5)` and `java` will exit with the exit code `5`.

Note that exit codes are not generally portable.  In `C` for example, to exit successfully, you should use `EXIT_SUCCESS` and not `0`.  While they are the same on many platforms `EXIT_SUCCESS` is defined to match the environment.

Some systems don't support exit code (they are rare).  Exit codes can be different than 0 for success (again relatively rare).  Java avoided all of these because it was promoting the throwing of Exceptions, over the reporting of error codes.  That said, sometimes to integrate with other systems, you really do need to emit an exit code.  Just don't think of it as a very "java" way of doing things.  An exception that gets to the top of the Stack in the JVM gives a stack trace dump which generally allows one to find and fix the issue far easier than any exit code.

Answer (score 0):

You're conflating a few things here. Processes on most operating systems have an exit code. This, by convention, often signals success or error of the process. In C this exit code is surfaced as the return value of the entry point.

Furthermore, in C it's a common pattern that functions return some special value (often 0 or `NULL`) on error, since there are no exceptions to signal that. Again, just a convention.

In Java both of those are fairly rare. Exceptions are often a nicer way of signalling an unexpected error condition, and the entry point doesn't have a return value.

Answer (score 0):

> Would the integer return show that there is/isn't an error returned?

That depends *entirely* on how the function that called it intends to use that value.  An integer return value may be used for an error code, or it may be used for a *count* of things (length of a string, number of elements in a tree, shabazzes frobbed), or it may indicate a value on a scale (temperature, elevation, dollars, etc.).

In some cases a value of `0` is an *out-of-band* value (not valid for the given domain, like the zero terminator at the end of a C-style string or a NULL pointer).  In other cases it's a perfectly valid data value (temperature, elevation, heading).

Notice that in Java `main` returns `void`, not `int`.  Java's philosophy of detecting and handling errors is different from C's.